# continue counting DIVS after skipping one div using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I want to skip the GoTop class div and continue counting the number of div's in parent class.

```
<div class="parent">
      <div>
      <div>
      <div>
      <div>
      <div>
      <div class="GoTop">
      <div>
      some more div's ......
    </div>
```

I have tried the following but all i am getting is size as 5, please help

```
size = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='parent']/div [not(contains(@class,'GoTop'))]")).size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tried code looks correct, I think you should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until divs element present with tried locator.

I would suggest you try using `By.cssSelector()` to achieve same as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
int size = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.parent > div:not(.GoTop)"))).size();
```

**Edited** :- If you're still getting less elements than total present, you can try using [`ExpectedCinditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan-org.openqa.selenium.By-java.lang.Integer-) which would wait until total number of elements found is equal or more than given number as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
int size = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(By.cssSelector("div.parent > div:not(.GoTop)"), 6)).size();
```

Comment: Or use this xpath instead `//div[@class='parent']/div[not(@class='GoTop')]`.

Comment: How do we know when all the divs have loaded ?

Comment: @testerjoe2 If these divs loaded through ajax wait  for ajax to complete other wise there is no directly way to know all divs or loaded or not except implement some hard code wait. Thanks

Comment: Why do you mean Didn't work?? Is there any exception or something other??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur - Is this a good way to check if whole page has loaded, before we do anything ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/39760528/6648326

Comment: You can try, may be it helps if divs loaded through ajax. Thank

Comment: @testerjoe2 or you can also try using `ExpectedCinditions.numberOfElementsToBeMore` Than which would wait until elements found equal or more than given number, try with edited answer and let me know..

Comment: @Saurabh - there is no exception all i am getting is 5 divs

Comment: @uma Did you tried with edited answer suggested as well??