# Selenium webdriver unable to identify links on a page using tagname

Tags: java, selenium

Selenium is displaying number of links on a page as 0 although there are many links on the page.

This is my code in java

```
dr.get("https://www.ebay.com");
List<WebElement> linksize = dr.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
System.out.println(linksize.size());
```

Output :
0

Comment: This is not giving me 0 as you said, when I run your code, output is 528

Comment: What version of firefox are you using ?

Comment: Worked in Firefox 48, Chrome 53 with Selenium 2.53.0

Answer (score 1):

Wait until page loads for links

Modify your code to

```
dr.get("https://www.ebay.com");
waitForLoad(dr); // Here you are calling the below method
List<WebElement> linksize = dr.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
System.out.println(linksize.size());
```

You can use the below method as your util and can call anytime

```
void waitForLoad(WebDriver driver) {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
            }
        };
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
}
```

Comment: "Interactive"  can be useful only when we bother about the content we want to validate (asserting), ex: if we want to validate for a text to present. But, what if we click any link or button that load other content in page (dynamically) and we want to validate that.?

 if we use "interactive" then the test may fails. So, there is a "complete", to rescue. However, it depends on what kind of test (asserting or performing any other events) you are performing..

Comment: Used your code. Still getting output as zero. However I am able to click on links on the page using xpath expressions.

Answer (score 0):

@Subhrapratim Bhattacharjee, it seems that you need to wait for the page to load. Try following code

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.ebay.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    List<WebElement> linksize = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.tagName("a")));//driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    System.out.println(linksize.size());
```

Comment: Using your code I am getting error :Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of any elements located by By.tagName: a (tried for 120 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)..     However I can click on links on the page using dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gh-as-a']")).click();

Comment: @Subhrapratim Bhattacharjee, put a thread.sleep(10000); just before WebDriverWait and see the result. The page has more than 500 links. In my case I can see 542 as count.